# Angular - trigger click event in test not working

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having this `directive` which is just working fine:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('app.core')
    .directive('selectOnClick', selectOnClick);

    // @ngInject
    function selectOnClick() {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            link : function (scope, element) {
                element.on('click', function () {
                    this.select();
                    scope.testValue++; // only to test if it is triggered
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

In my test, I want to check if the click event is triggered and if the element is selected. Like you can see below, I trigger a click event in the test and run `$scope.$digest()`, but *neither the scope variable is incremented nor the click event is triggered.* 
Any ideas why?

```
describe('test selectOnClickDirective', function () {
    'use strict';
    var $scope,
    $compile,
    element;
    beforeEach(module('app.core'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $compile = _$compile_;
            element = $compile('<input select-on-click type="text">')($scope);
            $scope.$digest();
        }));

    it('should trigger an click event', function () {
        $scope.testValue = 10;
        var input = element.find('input');
        input.trigger('click');
        $scope.$digest();

        expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(input);
        expect($scope.testValue).toEqual(11);
    });

    it('should select the element when clicked on it', function () {
        //expect(element.find('input').is(':selected')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: first add scope.$apply in order to have angular loop checking changes and apply them in your event callback or it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that `element.find` searches for child elements in this element. So I had to just use `element`.
Solution will be this:

```
  it('should trigger an click event', function () {
    $scope.testValue = 10;
    element.trigger('click');
    $scope.$digest();

    expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(element);
    expect($scope.testValue).toEqual(11);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
input.triggerHandler('click');
```

instead of your

```
input.trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element` that you've compiled, and use `triggerHandler` which passes a dummy event object to the handlers.

From the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): `triggerHandler()` - Passes a dummy event object to handlers.

So you need to write:

`element.triggerHandler('click');`